# How to use pinyin tone to filter the list of Chinese Characters with ibus?

Tags: ibus, input-method, chinese, pinyin

I use *Intelligent Pinyin Keyboard* with `ibus` in Ubuntu to input Chinese characters into my document.

The `input-method` is designed in such a way that one starts typing the characters that correspond to the `pinyin` associated with a character, and then it can select from a list of characters the one that matches the request.

**Example.**

[image]

As shown in the previous example, for each combination of `arabic` characters there is a long list of potential Chinese characters that might match it. This list of characters may correspond to `xue` pronounced with several kinds of tones, **e.g.** `xue`, `xue1`, `xue2`, `xue3`, `xue4`.

I would like to be able to use the the **tone number** to further filter out the list of Characters that is being presented to me, so that the length of the list shrinks as a whole and it is easier to go through it. **e.g.** If I type `yi1`, I would like to see only those characters matching exactly that `pinyin` and tone.

Unfortunately, it is impossible to do so, because pressing any `digit` from `1` to `0` causes the input method to choose one of the listed examples.

Is there any other `input-method`, a `patch` or a different configuration that can help me achieve my goal?

Note that I **don't want** to get `pinyin` text as a result (as asked in similar questions on this site), but the Chinese Characters.

Answer (score 0):

Pinyin IMEs are not designed to do this. *(But can you do this?)* To obtain the intended effect, two utilities should have been combined together:

1. Standard pinyin IME (e.g. *SunPinyin*) using ...
2. ... *English (US, intl with dead keys)* or *hanyu pinyin (m17n)* as a front input source.

I was looking for the same solution but, to my knowledge, it has not been developed yet.

**Bibliography:**

1. [*Chinese Input Methods
   in Ubuntu 10 - 18*.](https://www.pinyinjoe.com/linux/ubuntu-10-chinese-input-pinyin-chewing.htm)
2. [*Sogou IME (on Ubuntu): How to output pinyin with tone marks?*](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/28719/sogou-ime-on-ubuntu-how-to-output-pinyin-with-tone-marks)

Answer (score 0):

I concur with Christianus that I don't know of a pinyin+tone_filter implementation.

However, if you're willing to learn zhuyin, its implementations almost always default to using tones to filter.

In fact, it's kind of rare to find a zhuyin input that allows you to type without tones, but they do exist.

Anyway, best of luck.